# Spring Data JPA - Query with ElementCollection - Low Performance

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am having some performance issues with a simple query in Spring Data JPA.

Model:

```
@Entity
public class LogEntry {
    ..
    @NotNull
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<String> parameters;

    @ManyToOne
    private Guest guest;
    ..
}
```

Repository:

```
Page<LogEntry> findByGuestOrderByCreationDateDesc(Guest guest, Pageable pageable);
```

I want to display a list of log entries with all parameters. But the query is incredibly slow. After finding all entries, it starts to querying for the parameters for each entry.

Logs show a lot of these lines:

```
Hibernate: select parameters0_.LogEntry_id as LogEntry1_8_0_, parameters0_.parameters as paramete2_9_0_ from LogEntry_parameters parameters0_ where parameters0_.LogEntry_id=?
```

I am searching for a way to improve the query. I tried to use a join fetch without success.

```
@Query("select l from LogEntry l join fetch l.parameters where l.guest = ?1 order by l.creationDate desc")


Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=null,role=domain.guest.LogEntry.parameters,tableName={none},tableAlias=parameters1_,origin=null,columns={,className=null}}] [select count(l) from domain.guest.LogEntry l join fetch l.parameters where l.guest = ?1]
```

Comment: The problem is not with the query you provided. It's with the count query that Spring derives from the query. AFAIR, you can specify a countQuery on the Query annotation (which wouldn't jave the join fetch (whichshould be a left join fetc, BTW)). http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html#countQuery--

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
@Query("select logEntry from LogEntry logEntry join fetch logEntry.parameters as params join fetch logEntry.guest as guest where guest.id = :guestId order by logEntry.creationDate desc")
Page<LogEntry> findByGuestOrderByCreationDateDesc(@Param Long guestId, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: I still get this error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=params,role=domain.guest.LogEntry.parameters,tableName={none},tableAlias=parameters1_,origin=null,columns={,className=null}}] [select count(logEntry) from domain.guest.LogEntry logEntry join fetch logEntry.parameters as params join fetch logEntry.guest as guest where guest.id = :guestId]

Comment: I think, the query you tried might not work. Because you have added count(logEntry).  select count(logEntry) from domain.guest.LogEntry logEntry join fetch logEntry.parameters as params join fetch logEntry.guest as guest where guest.id = :guestId.   This can fixed using native query. Can you please specify the table names for these. So i can help you write the query for that.